# Batch string problems (searching a full line)

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, text, cmd

I have this string code:

```
set search=123
findstr /m %search% text.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo YES
) else (
echo NO
)
```

The text file is like this:

```
123
456
789
```

It works but if i have search as "1" it says "YES" but i want it to only say yes for a full line. Can any one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 findstr /m ^%search%$ text.txt
```

you need a regex.

From `findstr` help

> ^        Line position: beginning of line
>
> $        Line position: end of line

Comment: You would need to supply the /r flag to use this and then the passed string would be interpreted as regex as well.  While this would work in this case, and is the answer I almost supplied, this is not the most reliable solution to the problem presented.

Comment: @DaveBush - It is a good idea to explicitly specify the /R option, but it is not necessary. FINDSTR will detect the presence of a regex meta-character, and automatically interpret the search as a regex. Where you can get into trouble is if there are multiple search strings. If the 1st string is a valid regex, then all are treated as regex. If the 1st string does not have a meta-character, then none of the strings will be treated as regex, even if later strings do contain a meta-character.

Answer (score 2):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

/x   : Prints lines that match exactly.